# Help with installing Nvidia-410 drivers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, gpu

I have been having trouble installing the latest nvidia-410 driver to use with CUDA.  I can install them directly from Nvidia's website but it means that the package manager doesn't recognize that the official drivers are installed.  Attempts to install them via the terminal have failed as I get the following error.  Obviously I have done something wrong somewhere but not sure what.  Any help is appreciated.

```
nathan@BB-8:~$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-410
The following NEW packages will be installed
  nvidia-410
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 307 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/96.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 394 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 179510 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-410_410.79-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-410 (410.79-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-410_410.79-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package libglx-mesa0:amd64 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-410_410.79-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ninja Edit:

Worth adding this is the error I get with the manually installed Nvidia drivers

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.10-6ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3v5 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-410 : Depends: nvidia-410 (>= 410.79) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-410 : Depends: nvidia-410 (>= 410.79) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: @N0rbert  Thanks for linking that.  While the answer there wasn't the solution, it led me to to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1753796) where I fixed it with this command "sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken"  I guess the broken dependency prevented it from allowing it to update and fix the issue

Comment: Try using `aptitude` instead of `apt`